# alterView text Issue!

Tags: ios4

I want to show a button name on it's click that pop's up a alertView.I tried with the following code.But the titleLabel is not showing on the alertView.

### Code:

```
-(void) btnAction:(id) sender
{

    BeginingCell *cellObject;
    cellObject=[[BeginingCell alloc]init];
    NSString *str= [[NSString alloc] init];
    str=cellObject.ansBtn1.titleLabel.text;
    UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:str message:str delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil ];
    [alrt show];

}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few of issues:

1. You have unnecessary alloc/init calls with no corresponding call to `release`, so you are leaking memory.
2. You are attempting to access the `titleLabel` of an object that you just allocated, instead of the `titleLabel` associated with the button that was pressed (which I assume is what you want).  Depending upon what BeginingCell's `init` method does, you may get a nil string, a string with some default value, or even a crash due to attempting to access a field that has not been properly initialized.
3. You're also not releasing your UIAlertView when you are done with it.

You may have better luck with something like:

```
-(void) btnAction:(id) sender {
    NSString *str = ((UIButton*)sender).titleLabel.text;
    UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:str message:str 
        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil ];
    [alrt show];
    [alrt release];
}
```

Comment: i was getting nil value with my previous code.tell me how can i implement this method you kept blank.- (BeginingCell*) cellForButton:(UIButton*) button {
    //determine which cell corresponds to the given button, and return it
}

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju - How to implement it depends upon how your interface and backing objects are structured.  I can't tell you how to do it, because there isn't enough detail provided by the example code snippet to do so.

Comment: @aroth:there are nothing much in the BeginingCell actually.Just some outlets for the controls.

Comment: @aroth:Let's imagine the Begining Cell contais just the outlet for a button.how can i use it in that method?

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju - Okay, I've updated the code in my answer to something that I believe should work.